# Image is hidden inside button but I can see it when i put background color for it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

By default I can see my heart img in button. Once button is clicked it is changing to added to list but I can't see img here. Image is hidden here, I can see that using background color for the image. Not sure where I am doing wrong. thanks for your help in advance

```
changeHeart = () => {
  if (this.emptyHeart) {
    this.emptyHeart = false;
    document.getElementById('heartImage').src = '../../img/filledHeart.png';
    document.getElementById('heartImage').style.visibility = '';
   document.getElementById('addButtonText').innerHTML = "Added to List";
  } else {
    this.emptyHeart = true;
    document.getElementById('heartImage').src ='../../img/emptyHeart.png';
    document.getElementById('heartImage').style.visibility = 'hidden';
   document.getElementById('addButtonText').innerHTML = "Add to List";
  }
};


<button onClick={this.changeHeart} className="btn">
  <img id="heartImage" className="heartBtnImg" src={require('../../img/emptyHeart.png')} alt=""/>
  <span id="addButtonText" className="btntxt">Add to Wish List</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start with a tutorial on React before jumping in. You should use the state for this.

```
changeHeart = () => {
  if (this.state.emptyHeart) {
    this.setState({
      emptyHeart: false,
      imgSrc: require('../../img/filledHeart.png'),
      btnText: 'Added to List'
    });
  } else {
    this.setState({
      emptyHeart: true,
      imgSrc: require('../../img/emptyHeart.png'),
      btnText: 'Add to List'
    });
  }
};
```

In your render function:

```
<button onClick={this.changeHeart} className="btn">
  <img id="heartImage" className="heartBtnImg" src={this.state.imgSrc} alt=""/>
  <span id="addButtonText" className="btntxt">{this.state.btnText}</span>
</button>
```

I don't have access to your entire code, so please fix the paths and texts to suit your needs. You will also need to initialize your state in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks. do you recommend any tutorial for react?

Comment: Back when I started egghead.io had some free video tutorials by the creator of react and redux themselves.